# Rowtype and type supported in sqldeveloper.ink

Tags: sql, oracle

Are % Rowtype and %type not supported by sqldeveloper.ink ?

Comment: Please have a look at this link.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @Ullas I copied this link to my answer, but then I realized it points to the MySQL documentation, not to the documentation for the Oracle database <RANT> I wish Oracle would use sensible URLs / page titles. It's absolutely impossible to know whether Google took you to the MySQL or Oracle RDBMS documentation pages </RANT>

Answer (score 2):

To clarify: *SQL Developer* is just a client for the Oracle *database*, so you're looking for a function in the Oracle database.

You need to decide:

- whether you want to get the value as a `DATE` (which is actually a datetime) or as a `TIMESTAMP` (which has higher precision (fractions of seconds))
- whether you want it for the timezone of the session (which usually equals that of the client) or the server

**Functions**

- SYSDATE (date, timezone of server)
- SYSTIMESTAMP (timestamp, timezone of server)
- CURRENT_DATE (date, timezone of current session)
- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (timestamp, timezone of current session)

**Example query**:

```
select 
  sysdate, 
  systimestamp, 
  current_date, 
  current_timestamp 
from dual
```

**Further reading**

[Oracle blog entry about the difference between SYSDATE and CURRENT_DATE](https://blogs.oracle.com/ecmarch/entry/be_aware_of_the_difference)

[Oracle documentation of SYSDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm)

[Oracle documentation of CURRENT_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions036.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
SYSDATE();
```

Returns the current datetime.